# How can I to get subclass return types when calling functions defined on the base class?

Tags: python, inheritance, typing, pylance

I'm trying to write a class hierarchy in Python so that subclasses can override a method `predict` to have a more narrow return type which is itself a subclasses of the parent's return type. This seems to work fine when I instantiate an instance of the subclass and call `predict`; the returned value has the expected narrow type. However, when I call a different function defined on the base class (`predict_batch`) which itself calls `predict`, the narrow return type is lost.

Some context: My program has to support using two types of image segmentation models, "instance" and "semantic". The outputs of these two models are very different, so I was thinking to have symmetric class hierarchy to store their outputs (ie. `BaseResult`, `InstResult`, and `SemResult`). This would allow some of the client code to be general by using `BaseResults` when it doesn't need to know which specific type of model was used.

Here is a toy code example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import List

from overrides import overrides

##################
# Result classes #
##################


class BaseResult(ABC):
    """Abstract container class for result of image segmentation"""

    pass


class InstResult(BaseResult):
    """Stores the result of instance segmentation"""

    pass


class SemResult(BaseResult):
    """Stores the result of semantic segmentation"""

    pass


#################
# Model classes #
#################


class BaseModel(ABC):
    def predict_batch(self, images: List) -> List[BaseResult]:
        return [self.predict(img) for img in images]

    @abstractmethod
    def predict(self, image) -> BaseResult:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class InstanceSegModel(BaseModel):
    """performs instance segmentation on images"""

    @overrides
    def predict(self, image) -> InstResult:
        return InstResult()


class SemanticSegModel(BaseModel):
    """performs semantic segmentation on images"""

    @overrides
    def predict(self, image) -> SemResult:
        return SemResult()


########
# main #
########

# placeholder for illustration 
images = [None, None, None]

model = InstanceSegModel()
single_result = model.predict(images[0])  # has type InstResult
batch_result = model.predict_batch(images)  # has type List[BaseResult]
```

In the code above, I would like for `batch_result` to have type `List[InstResult]`.

At runtime, none of this matters, and my code executes just fine. But the static type checker (Pylance) in my editor (VS Code) doesn't like how the client code assumes `batch_result` is the more narrow type. I can only think of these two possible solutions, but neither feels clean to me:

1. Use the `cast` function from the `typing` module
2. Override `predict_batch` in the subclasses even though the logic doesn't change

Comment: I also have had this question for a long time

Comment: Use a type variable bound to the base return type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) and inheritance together to override/narrow an annotation in a parent class

```
from typing import List, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


class BaseModel(ABC, Generic[T]):
    def predict_batch(self, images: List) -> List[T]:
        return [self.predict(img) for img in images]

    @abstractmethod
    def predict(self, image) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class InstanceSegModel(BaseModel[InstResult]):
    """performs instance segmentation on images"""

    @overrides
    def predict(self, image) -> InstResult:
        return InstResult()


class SemanticSegModel(BaseModel[SemResult]):
    """performs semantic segmentation on images"""

    @overrides
    def predict(self, image) -> SemResult:
        return SemResult()


images = [None, None, None]

model = InstanceSegModel()
single_result = model.predict(images[0])  # has type InstResult
batch_result = model.predict_batch(images)  # has type List[InstResult]
```